# Как при повороте экрана скрыть статус бар?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Как при повороте экрана скрыть статус бар и app bar? Приложение Windows phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

При создании страницы запоминаем текущую ориентацию:

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

...

private ApplicationViewOrientation previousOrientation;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.previousOrientation = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation;
}
```

Подписываемся на событие `SizeChanged` страницы, в обработчике проверяем текущую ориентацию. Если она отличается от предыдущей, прячем аппбар и статус бар:

```
private async void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newOrientation = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation;
    if (newOrientation != this.previousOrientation)
    {
        this.BottomAppBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
    }
}
```

(Аппбар был добавлен с помощью тега `<Page.BottomAppBar>`.)